# Where is the default color of <mark> element defined?

Tags: css, html

I see the default `<mark>` background color as yellow. Where is it defined?

I didn't find it in the [reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-mark-element), there is no corresponding color in [CSS2 system colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors).

Is the color always the same? Does it depend on browser or GUI settings? Is there any standard or recommendation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 spec, in the [rendering section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering) has this:

> mark { background: yellow; color: black; } /* this color is just a
>   suggestion and can be changed based on implementation feedback */

which leaves it pretty open to change. In any case, browsers are not required to follow the CSS advice in the rendering section in order to be compliant.

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. I hoped it was something like system default highlight color. If the background of parent element is yellow or the color set to yellow, that spoils readability. Anyway, the reference is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The `<mark>` tag is like a highlighted piece of text as defined by W3C:

> The mark element represents a run of text in one document marked or highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another context.

The official documentation on W3.org states the default display properties:

```
mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black; 
}
```

- [`<mark>` - HTML5 | W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/mark.html)

Comment: @JanTuroň not at all. Both our answers grab information from W3.org but just use different references. I'm sure whatwg will eventually be up to date but as it is community driven and unofficial, its down to the general public to make sure its correct (which it isnt always)